# create a field that display value from an other one?

Tags: entities, nodes

I'll try to give a clearfull explanation of my question... but it's an hard one to explain, and my english is not really good... but let's try and I hope someone could help me. :)

I have a site running with Drupal 7

In this site I have an event calendar (with date)

And the entity registration module.

The point is:

When my user create a multiple event date I get a display like this:

> ```
>  event 1 - date_of_event_1
>  event 2 - date_of_event_2
>  event 3 - date_of_event_3
>
>  event description
>
>  registration form:
>
>  name:
>  e-mail:
> ```

What I want is to be able to have a field in my registration form like that:

> ```
> Choose your date: date_of_event_1 []  |  date_of_event_2 []
> ([] = some check boxes)
> ```

So I search for a module that allow my form to display a field referencing my dates...

I can easily display my dates values on a view. So I think there is a way to use the same filter on a field?

I've made some researches but I didn't find anything.

Maybe someone heard about something like that?

Thanks for reading!

Just adding some informations:

I have some hopes with the field-reference module...

But here the problem is my registration form is an other type of content and it's display in the related node by using a field "registration" (that came with the module)

So field reference doesn't find my date value in my form because it's not really in the same content. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is suited to your needs but maybe the [entity reference module](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) might be able to help you :

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:
>
> A generic entity reference field Four widgets:
>   Two implemented on top of the Options module (Select and Radios/Checkboxes),
>   Two autocomplete
>   widgets (one with one text field per entry, one tag-style with
>   comma-separated entries in the same text field)
>   Two formatters:
>   A
>   "Label" formatter, with optional link that displays the label of the
>   referenced entity (the node title, the user name, etc.)
>   A "Rendered
>   entity" formatter, that renders the references entity using a
>   configurable view mode Integration with Views (for both forward and
>   backward references)
>            Integration with Entity Metadata (and as a
>   consequence with Search API and the like) Integration with Devel
>   generate Integration with Feeds and Migrate (>= 2.3) for painless data
>   import This modules depends on Entity API and CTools.